# One Ember Data Model used in multiple routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Our app has one `Event` model and we want to use it on different routes on the Ember app. It is used both on the user's profile route as well as on a newsfeed route. So one time it is sideloaded with the user model and the other times it is just loaded from the server directly.

The problem now is, that when you go from one route to the other one, which also uses the `Event` model, it shows the models from both routes, even though it should just show the models from that one particular route.
I suppose this happens because ember-data caches the models and that any subsequent calls to `App.Event.find()` just append to the model.

Is there any good way to fix that? One solution I can think of, is using the `.reload()` function, but this could add a lot of unnecessary API calls. We've also tried subclassing the model (to have both `UserEvent`, `NewsfeedEvent`) but that just introduced new problems. Anyway, help is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the event model.  Would you mind giving me an example of why you'd like two different instances of the "same" model on the page?  This seems to go against the single source of truth paradigm, unless I'm just not getting something.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Do you mean with page the whole ember-app, or a single route? If you mean the first one, because we want events to be displayed on a newsfeed and on the user's profile, with the difference, that on the profile it is just displaying the user's events and on the newsfeed it is showing all different kind of events. Does that clarify things a bit more?

Comment: If you mean the second one (mutliple instances of the same model on a single route), that is exactly what we don't want but what ember seems to do.

Comment: When you say event model, is it safe to assume you are talking about a collection of event models?  Some of them are user events, some of them newsfeed events.  Part of the end result is you would like to filter out the user events from the newsfeed events (I'm guessing on this).

Comment: yep, it is a collections of event model. Your guess is half-right I would say: Newsfeed events are just events from all different kind of users. Like the fb newsfeed, so it can be events from the user himself, or other users. Though on the profile you are right, we just want the user events. The idea was, that this gets handled by the server via: `App.Event.find()` which just returns the events from the logged in user and `App.Event.find({q : 'newsfeed'})` where the server then returns mixed logged-in-user-events and others (but that shouldn't really be embers concern imo)